# Error 503 Service Unavailable - Varnish Cache

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, varnish

Setup Varnish cache on LAMP

When visiting my website -> www.arintoker.com getting the error below.

```
Error 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable

Guru Meditation:

XID: 529248319
```

when I run `varnishlog` I get the following output

```
132 FetchError   - http first read error: -1 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)
  133 BackendClose - default
  132 VCL_call     - error
  132 VCL_return   - deliver
  132 VCL_call     - deliver
  132 VCL_return   - deliver
  132 TxProtocol   - HTTP/1.1
  132 TxStatus     - 503
  132 TxResponse   - Service Unavailable
  132 TxHeader     - Server: Varnish
  132 TxHeader     - Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  132 TxHeader     - Retry-After: 5
  132 TxHeader     - Content-Length: 418
  132 TxHeader     - Accept-Ranges: bytes
  132 TxHeader     - Date: Sat, 27 Aug 2016 20:07:36 GMT
  132 TxHeader     - X-Varnish: 529248853
  132 TxHeader     - Age: 17
  132 TxHeader     - Via: 1.1 varnish
  132 TxHeader     - Connection: close
  132 Length       - 418
  132 ReqEnd       - 529248853 1472328439.180813074 1472328456.191231966 0.000165224 17.010340691 0.000078201
  132 SessionClose - error
```

When I setup Varnish Cache I followed the guide on DigitalOcean([link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-varnish-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04--3))

*Let me know what other reports/resources could be helpful for resolving this issue. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I manage to solve this error by increasing the timeout.

`sudo nano /etc/varnish/default.vcl`
and having the following config settings:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127..0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;  
}
```

Although 600s as timeout is probably too much, you can have much lower setting which can work for you. For further help read [this](https://groups.drupal.org/node/28604) thread.

PS: I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Varnish can not talk to your backend. Maybe this can help: 
http://www.technoreply.com/solving-dreaded-varnish-503-error/

Comment: I actually tried all the steps and the last time they worked. However, this time with all those changes applied I still the issue persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve this. My website is a WordPress website so it often that the system receives a brute force attack on the /wp-admin panel. But this time I also noticed the same memory and CPU > 90% alerts from New Relic.

So I ran `netstat -natp | grep varnish`to figure out which IP was attacking me.

then proceeded to permanently block the IP with my server firewall.

This resolved the issue. Hope this helps someone!